# Deleting a string from a dynamic array and making that array one smaller

Tags: c++, arrays

My class assignment is to create a program using OOP that creates a dynamic array that can act like a vector. My remove entry function is crashing when I run it. After messing around with it for a while I can't seem to make it stop crashing no matter what I do. Here are the instructions for this function in particular.

The function should search dynamicArray for the string.If not found, it returns false. If found, it creates a new dynamic array one element smaller than dynamicArray. It should copy all elements except the input string into the new array, delete dynamicArray, decrement size, and return true.

```
bool dynamicStringArray::deleteEntry(std::string oldString)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (dynamicArray[i].compare(oldString) == 0){
            std::string* shortArray = new std::string[size - 1];

            delete &dynamicArray[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
                shortArray[j] = dynamicArray[j];

            size--;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                dynamicArray[j] = shortArray[j];

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to stop it from crashing by commenting out everything in the method body except the return, if this is where the problem is.

Comment: Yes I have done that and the error is in fact in the if statement body

Comment: Are you sure you need to copy the elements from `0` to `size -1`? You just deleted the one at index `i`, and `i < size`, not necessarily `i == size -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit of misunderstanding about what

```
delete &dynamicArray[i];
```

does.

It does not remove the `i-th` entry from `dynamicArray`. It tries to deallocate memory of one objet -- the `i-th` object. That in itself is cause for undefined behavior.

You may not call `delete` on a pointer unless it was returned by a call to `new`.

The second problems is that `dynamicArray` continues to have that pointer as the `i-th` element.

Here's an updated `if` statement that should work.

```
if (dynamicArray[i].compare(oldString) == 0) {
   std::string* shortArray = new std::string[size - 1];

   // Copy everything form dynamicArray to shortArray except
   // the i-th element.
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
      shortArray[j] = dynamicArray[j];
   }

   for (int j = i+1; j < size; j++)
   {
      shortArray[j-1] = dynamicArray[j];
   }

   // Delete old array
   delete dynamicArray;

   // Make the newly allocated array the array of
   // the object.
   dynamicArray = shortArray;

   // Decrement the size
   --size;

   return 1;
}
```